# How to join edges in the cylinder to the center in a symmetrical way?

Tags: edit-mode, faces, edges

[image: Cylinder with a base created by joining edges]I'm starting from extruding a circle along Z to have a cylinder without the basis. I want to create a basis like that in the photo, with all the vertices joined in the middle edge of the cylinder. How I can achieve that?

I don't want alternatives, I want to know how to achieve that starting from the point explained above.
Thanks in advance.

Cristian Palmas

Comment: What about scaling the selected vertices just in the Y direction and entering the value 0?

Comment: Yes, I got that in the end. I forgot that simple scaling to 0 could work. Thanks.